# GetListItemsAsync to retrieve files from SharePoint 2007

Tags: web-services, 2007, development

I want to retrieve only the documents that are present inside a specific folder of a document library using GetListItemsAsync method.

Here is how i call it:

```
sc.GetListItemsAsync("MyDocLib", null, null, null, null, 
    XElement.Parse(@"<QueryOptions><Folder>MyFolder</Folder></QueryOptions>"),
    null);
```

The call is returning all the documents inside "MyDocLib" and not only those that are in "MyFolder".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
sc.GetListItemsAsync("MyDocLib", null, null, null, null, 
    XElement.Parse(@"<QueryOptions><Folder>MyDocLib/MyFolder</Folder></QueryOptions>"),
    null);
```

Notice the document library name before the folder name.

Hope this helps!